# How to apply two ngIf on single html element with two different conditions

Tags: angular

How to apply two ngIf on single html element with two different conditions like

```
div class="sidebar" *ngIf="!this.router.url === '/login'">
    <!-- *ngIf="!route.isActive('/signup' || '/login')  " -->
<div class="sidebar-overlay"></div>
<div class="sidebar-coverlay">
    <div class="sidebar-logo">...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use && operator, like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!route.isActive('/signup') && !route.isActive('/login')">
    // your code
</div>
```

&& operator combines the two conditions (AND operator of logic gates)

```
(condition1) && (condition2)
```

means, both condition1 and condition2 has to be true in order to display the content inside your div

Comment: can we use || operator

Comment: Yeah, you need to formulate that

Comment: Which means, build the logic. || is the OR operator, so that you can combine the conditions like (condition 1) OR (condition 2).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of condition like this:

```
!route.isActive('/signup' || '/login')
```

you should write it as a two separate conditions:

```
*ngIf="!route.isActive('/signup') && !route.isActive('/login')"
```

So, your `div` should look like:

```
<div class="sidebar" *ngIf="!route.isActive('/signup') && !route.isActive('/login')">
```